# Discover what i18n keys are looked up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I'm using Formtastic to display a form, but it is not looking up the label value I expect.

It's defined in the yaml file as:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      my_model:
        foo:
```

and it used to work in rails 2.3 but is now failing after upgrading the app to rails 3.2 and newer formtastic.  I can only guess that it is looking for something else.

Is there a way to log every call to translate to see what is being looked up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.   Formtastic was configured with:

```
 Formtastic::FormBuilder.label_str_method = :titleize
```

which bypassed the humanize method that actually looks up I18n data.